# Emoji on MySQL and PHP: why some symbol yes other not?

Tags: php, mysql, emoji, utf8mb4

After reading all the topics about emoji on SO I'm bounded to ask for some help. 
Question seems to be almost the same: I got an iPhone App sending via PHP emoji to MySQL DB, I can see some symbol on records, as example "umbrella" and "cloud" but other not (angry face, smiling face, and other).

Why some yes and other not?

- MySQL Collation: utf8mb_unicode_ci
- Table collation: utf8mb_unicode_ci
- Field, varchar, collation: utf8mb_unicode_ci

PHP setup:

```
    mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4");
    mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8mb4");
```

The symbols not showed inside the record are shown as question mark "?"

Answer (score 11):

Some emoji are encoded using 3 bytes. If your computers supports emoji, here are the 3 byte emoji:

☺❤✨❕❔✊✌✋☝☀☔☁⛄⚡☎➿✂⚽⚾⛳♠♥♣♦〽☕⛪⛺⛲⛵✈⛽⚠♨1⃣2⃣3⃣4⃣5⃣6⃣7⃣8⃣9⃣0⃣#⃣⬆⬇⬅➡↗↖↘↙◀▶⏪⏩♿㊙㊗✳✴♈♉♊♋♌♍♎♏♐♑♒♓⛎⭕❌©®™

The rest are encoded using 4 bytes and will not work unless you update mysql to utf8mb4. It sounds like you did not fully upgrade to utf8mb4 in some way.

Comment: Thank you very much Jake, I will search in your direction. Right now I'm pretty sure I converted the target fields and the table in the right collation but I must missed something. I will update this topic. Thanx

Comment: I've verified and you're right the 3 bytes emoji are represented ok. What I miss is where I need to change collation. The field where I must record the emoji has got utf8mb4_unicode_ci collation. The Table that contains that field has got utf8mb4_unicode_ci collation. In the General Settings (phpMyAdmin) I see that MySQL collation is utf8_general_ci and when I try to change to utf8mb4_unicode_ci it seems to automatically back to the previous setting. I don't know if the problem is for this reason. I will keep searching.

Comment: @Fabrizio I’ve written [a detailed guide on how to upgrade from `utf8` to `utf8mb4`](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4) — perhaps it helps you.

Comment: What is the best version of 'utf8mb4' to use? In MySQL, you have many options for utf8mb4, such as `utf8mb4_bin`, `utf8mb4_general_ci`, `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`, `utf8mb4_roman_ci`, and many others. Any thoughts/ideas/suggestions on the differences in these that would help a developer decide which is best to pick for storing emojis in a MySQL database?

Comment: I'm just going to pick `utf8mb4_general_ci` for now, but I don't know any of the differences, so if there's a better one for me to pick, please provide insight.

Comment: The difference is in how mysql will sort the data. If you care that e and é and ê are sorted absolutely correctly, then use the slower utf8mb4_unicode_ci, but if it doesn't matter, use the faster utf8mb4_general_ci